# How to print number from a dropdown list in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to print the number that corresponds to the list of classes I defined in the variable `pixelClass`, but when I click on my button, it only prints the label name, not the number. How can I make it to print only the number?

My code:

```
var pixelClass = {
  'All' : 0,
  'Soil' : 2,
  'Water' : 3,
  'Dead Grass' : 5,
  'Marsh' : 6,
  'Scrub' : 7,
  'Grass' : 8,
  'Forested Upland' : 9,
  'Forested Wetland' : 10,
  'Developed' : 11,
  };

var classSelector = ui.Select({
  items: Object.keys(pixelClass),
  value: null,
  style: {width: '35%', stretch: 'horizontal',padding:'0px 0px 0px 10px'}
});

var Button = ui.Button({
  label: 'Print Value', 
  style: {width: '45%', stretch: 'horizontal',padding:'0px 0px 0px 10px'},
  onClick: function getValue(){
    return print(classSelector.getValue())
  }
})

var panel = ui.Panel({
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('vertical'),
  style: {width: '350px'}   });
panel.add(classSelector)
panel.add(Button)
ui.root.insert(0, panel);
```

Link:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/91c0a53623b8ea0a901d2f7751884e3c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you specified

```
items: Object.keys(pixelClass),
```

the values that the `ui.Select` has *are* the names in `pixelClass`. In order to get the values of `pixelClass`, you need to look up the name in `pixelClass`.

```
  onClick: function getValue(){
    print(pixelClass[classSelector.getValue()]);
  }
```